# Change a specific block's font size using css

Tags: css, drupal-7

I'm a CSS noob and have not been able to find a solution to my problem.
I run a drupal 7 website.

I need to change a specific block's font size. Using the CSS injector module I've only been able to change the change the font of all blocks using:

```
.block {font-size: 80%}
```

Obviously that makes sense as it's got a global application.

The div id for the block is: `block-views-new-deals-block-block`

The div class for the block is: `block block-views contextual-links-region`

There's also another div class called: `view view-new-deals-block view-id-new_deals_block view-display-id-block view-dom-id-6b4fc98a10e3af5ef7e512f56f8d8c4c`
I've tried this with no luck:

```
.block-views-new-deals-block-block {font-size: 80%;}
```

I've been messing around with the developer option in Firefox but haven't had any success. I don't know what to try next.

Comment: add you HTML structure for more understanding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's difficult to say without the whole HTML, but if the block you want to change the font-size has an ID you can use it like:

```css
#block-views-new-deals-block-block { font-size: 80% }
```